# Как отобразить выбранный элемент списка, а так же вывести полный список элементов для изменения

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, я использую следующий код на странице для добавления данных

```
<select name="nomceh">
        <?php
        $resum = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Nomer_cekha FROM cekha ");

        while($fila=mysqli_fetch_row($resum)) {
            echo "<option value='".$fila['0']."'>".$fila['0']."</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select><br>
```

Но я не могу его использовать на странице редактирования данных, он не отображает выбранный элемент списка. Как отобразить выбранный элемент списка, а так же вывести полный список элементов для изменения.

Вот изображение того, что я имею ввиду, когда я захожу в редактирование, там уже выбран пункт 2, но я могу изменить его на другой.

Подробности: У меня родительская таблица cekha с первичным ключом Nomer_cekha, но таблица которую я изменяю другая, personal и там внешний ключ Nomer_ceha_fk.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

По такому принципу

```
<select name="nomceh">
    <? $resum = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT Nomer_cekha FROM cekha') ?>

    <? while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($resum)) { ?>
        <? $checked = ($nomceh == $fila['0'] ? 'checked' : '') ?>
        <option <?=$checked?> value="<?=$fila['0']?>"><?=$fila['0']?></option>
    <? } ?>

</select>
```

Comment: Подскажите еще момент! У меня родительская таблица cekha  с первичным ключом Nomer_cekha, но таблица которую я изменяю другая, personal и там внешний ключ Nomer_ceha_fk. Поменяется ли из-за этого код, который вы написали?

Comment: @Roman Verner, этот код так или иначе будет подвержен изменениям, т.к. он служит для описания принципа. Так что пробуйте менять в нём соответствующие значения на свои.

Comment: Понял вас, спасибо!